# Use variable for amount of time in Groupdate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

I am using the [Groupdate Gem](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) to filter my objects based on date but it seems like the only way to call the function is like so:

```
@foo = Model.group_by_hour(:created_at).count
@foo = Model.group_by_month(:created_at).count
@foo = Model.group_by_day(:created_at).count
...
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to use a variable so that a user could select whether to filter by month, year, day, etc.

**Is there a way to insert a variable into this function to allow for more flexible code?**

Something like:

```
@foo = Model."group_by_#{ time_variable }"(:created_at).count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like?

```
@foo = Model.send("group_by_#{time_variable}", :created_at).count
```

or perhaps the gem supports the following:

```
@foo = Model.group_by(time_variable => :created_at).count
```

Comment: I went with the first option!  Thanks.  Didn't think to include the `:created_at` seperated by a  comma